# Are open balls Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $n=1,2,3,...$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$ is every open ball $B_r(x):=\{y\in\ \mathbb{R}^n:\|y-x\|<r\}$ a bounded Lipschitz domain?

I am having troubles understanding Lipschitz domains. My teacher said that a bounded Lipschitz domain is a domain whose boundary is the graph of a Lipschitz function. I really don't understand the meaning of that claim. I am reading the [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominio_de_Lipschitz) definition and now I am really confused.

Can somebody help me with this problem? I'll appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the $n=2$ situation: the unit circle looks locally like the graph of the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is Lipschitz on $(-1/2,1/2)$.

That is, if you take a point $x_0$ on the circle, an open ball with small radius at the centered at that point, then the intersection of the circle with the ball is a after rotation and translation part of the graph of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Moreover, points near $x_0$ inside/outside the domain are below/above the graph.

Comment: but if $n=1$, then $B_r(x)$ is not an interval? Are intervals also Lipschitz domains?

Comment: typo meant $n=2$ :)

Comment: Mmmm I think I get it with $n=2$. But what if $n=1$. The boundary of an open interval consists only of two points. How do I construct a Lipschitz function with only two points?

Comment: Thats quite the trivial situation: take two Lipschitz functions for each boundary point.